# How did Christine Palmer protect Doctor Strange?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, object-identification, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, Doctor Strange uses the *dreamwalking* technique in a surprising way and consequently comes under attack from the spirits of the damned.

Christine Palmer is present and protects Doctor Strange. She battles the spirits quite effectively using an artefact. What is the artefact and how did Christine Palmer know how to use it so well?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The item [Earth-838 Christine](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Christine_Palmer_(Earth-838)) used against the Souls of the Damned was named by her as the **[Brazier of Bom'Galiath](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Brazier_of_Bom%27Galiath)**.

From the Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki:

> The Brazier of Bom'Galiath is a relic in possession of the Masters of the Mystic Arts.

We have relatively little info on Earth-838 Christine's history, so there's no direct explanation as to why she knew how to use the Brazier. She clearly recognised it though, indicating that she had some knowledge of it, and she'd already been shown to be familiar with the Earth-838 version of the [Sands of Nisanti](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sands_of_Nisanti); sufficiently familiar to incorporate them into the special handcuffs used to bind Dr. Strange.

> EARTH-838 CHRISTINE: I developed those using the Sands of Nisanti... one of 838-Stephen's magical relics.
>
> <sub>*Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022)</sub>

It's possible that she was introduced to these artefacts through her relationship with [Earth-838 Strange](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Stephen_Strange_(Earth-838)), but it seems more likely that she took it upon herself to study them after it was determined that he and his variants posed a threat to realities. As she was working for the [Illuminati](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Illuminati), [Earth-838 Mordo](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Karl_Mordo_(Earth-838)) would likely have granted her access to, and intel on, anything she requested, within reason.

---

The [Earth-199999](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-199999) version of the item made a brief appearance in *Doctor Strange* (2016), during Strange's first fight with [Kaecilius](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Kaecilius), about halfway through the film.

---

A version of the item [also exists in the comics](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Brazier_of_Bom%27Galiath). It made its first appearance in *[Mighty Thor Vol. 1 #443](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mighty_Thor_Vol_1_443)*, where it was used by Strange as part of a spell which enabled [Eric Masterson](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eric_Masterson_(Earth-616)) to temporarily trespass within [Mephisto's realm](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mephisto%27s_Realm), for as long as the flames continued to burn.  The instant the flames died out, Masterson was pulled back to Strange's [Sanctum Sanctorum](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sanctum_Sanctorum).

> DR. STRANGE: One last caution, Masterson--! A spell of this magnitude carries a heavy toll, and I can only maintain it so long as the Brazier of Bom'Galiath continues to burn!
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*Mighty Thor Vol. 1 #443* (January, 1992)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Christine Palmer is something like the head scientist of the Illuminati and has worked closely with Dr. Strange of her universe, therefore it's very likely that she has profound knowledge about many magical artifacts. Also, the bowl was presented prominently in a glass cabinet, which indicates that it's one of the more popular artifacts.

Besides that, the room was stuffed with artifacts, so that she would just have picked another one, if she wasn't familiar with this artifact.